# Regex to match if...else statements?

Tags: php, regex

I need to make a regex that matches "if" structures. EG:

```
if(whatever) {  } else { adsffdsa } else if() { }
```

It doesn't matter if the code blocks and expressions are valid, only that the structure is correct. I got to this point:

```
/^if\s*\((.*?)\)\s*{(.*?)}\s*//
```

However when I try to continue to match else and else if the regex stops working. I tried these two things:

```
/^if\s*\((.*?)\)\s*{(.*?)}\s*else?/
/^if\s*\((.*?)\)\s*{(.*?)}\s*(else|else\s*if(\s*))?/
```

How can I make my regex match the else statements if there are any?

Comment: Is there any concern of nested blocks?

Comment: Is this about you trying to build a tokenizer/parser? (It's not completely infeasible to mimic PHP/JS syntax in a regex, but advisable it ain't either.)

Comment: No, you don't need to use regular expressions. http://php.net/book.tokenizer Seriously: This wont end well.

Comment: no, I don't care anything inside the statement as I'll loop through it's inner parts later

Comment: yes, actually it is. I only want to use regex for the if statements. I already built a tokenizer, the thing is that it's driving me crazy to parse tokens into if statements and functions. It will save a lot of time to use a regex

Comment: @Liso22 If you use regular expressions to evalute the whole source, you didn't build a tokenizer, but ... don't know, something scary. No, it will not save a lot of time to use regex, because you will end with months of debugging and bugfixing just to introduce new problems. Also (sorry to said that) somebody (the PHP-core) already built a already working tokenizer ;) tl;dr: Regex is not the tool of choice here.

Comment: KinCrunch's opposition to regex's should not be quite so ironclad; it _IS_ the tool of choice, but only for an A-level regexer.  And frankly, if you need regex's that badly you should be using perl, not php.

Comment: I'd heard things against regexes for this use before so idk. There must be some truth in it. You can see my tokenizer here: http://momemi.com/bot/3 I might start parsing it and forget about the regex but I haven't found much info about how to continue.

Comment: Regular expressions are the wrong tool for this job. Build a parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, this should get you pointed in the right direction but it's going to get ugly the more sophisticated you make it.

```
/^if\s*\((.*?)\)\s*{(.*?)}(\s*(else|else\s+if\s*\((.*?)\))\s*{(.*?)})*/
```

Hope it helps

It matched this for me so it should match most cases (as long as it doesn't have comments anywhere around the block):

```
if(whatever) {  } else { adsffdsa } else if() { }
else if() {}
```

Comment: How does that work on `if(...) { if(...) { } else { } } else { if(...) { } else { } }`?

Comment: it doesnt consider any nested statements so these won't match, in the question comments the creator said the following:
"no, I don't care anything inside the statement as I'll loop through it's inner parts later – Liso22"

Comment: Is it going to handle comments?  How about curly brackets inside of quoted strings?

Comment: It is "harder" (it is possible to assume the code doesn't contain such case) to break inside the expression (since it is rare to have `)` and `{` right next to each other inside), but the regex breaks like a twig when nested if is involved (it is normal to have this).

Comment: It will accept anything inside the curly brackets (comments, code, whatever) but nothing outside of it.
It simply checks for the following:
starts with if followed by * spaces
then looks for ( with any anything followed by )
then * spaces followed by { with anything followed by }

(these next checks are done 0 or more times so it will match multiple else and else if statemnts)
then it checks for else or else * spaces if
followed by * spaced ( anything )
* spaces { anything }

Not quite as comprehensive as a compiler but it will match simple if else if else statements

Comment: @DanielWardin: Yes, I saw that comment, but it was mistaken. (If an OP said "My computer isn't plugged in, but that's O.K., I don't need to give it electricity, I just need to turn it on!", I hope you wouldn't just give an answer that explained how to push the power button.)

Comment: @ruakh Yeah I understand what you mean but this piece of reg ex should get him started and since he has a basic understanding I hope he will be able to modify it to his needs (I assume some level of understanding and if the question owner wants more then he/she can drop a comment and I will expand upon the answer) ;)

Comment: I plan to loop this through each level (expressions/code blocks) and to use a tokenizer afterwards. Curly brackets inside quotes are simply ignored since i have a `/^(".*?")/` token for strings

Comment: @DanielWardin: No: this problem cannot be solved with regexes, or at least, not in anything remotely resembling this way. Your existing regex could perhaps be improved, but it cannot be improved to the point of supporting arbitrarily nested blocks, because such nesting cannot be expressed by regular expressions. (It requires a [context-free grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar), which regular expressions cannot handle.)

Comment: @ruakh I understand that to make this work really well you shouldn't user reg ex but since the question owner asked for a regex solution I provided a regex solution. I understand your point but I simply answered the question.
'How can I make my regex match the else statements if there are any?'

Comment: @ruakh: you are right, I'll give up on regexes. The answer is correct anyway.